# View an .pem vertificate file content

Tags: debian, certificate, nano

I need to view a `.pem` file content. After researching little in the web, I find 2 ways to view the content,

A. I executed the command provided below,

```
   sudo keytool -printcert -file cak.artt.pem
```

The output is,

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Failed to parse input
```

B. I executed the command,

```
sudo openssl x509 -in cak.artt.pem -text
```

The output is,

```
unable to load certificate
139976958314128:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:696:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

I read that this can happen in the case of `APNS certificates`, which combines private key & certificate into one `.pem`. The instruction is to Separate them into 2 files using a text editor and the above commands will work.

How to do that and view the content of the certificate? I have Debian 8 environment. Btw, I have JDK 9 installed on the machine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error message sometimes happens when you try to read a DER encoded certificate.

You can use this command to view DER encoded certificate details:

```
openssl x509 -in YOUR_FILENAME -inform der -text -noout
```